# Connect to the database using wizard in c# using visual studio 2008 SPI version

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am a student and I am learning how to connect to access database using wizard in c# and I using visual studio 2008 SPI version I am getting the following error with I try to add the data source:

An unexpected error has occurred.

Error Message: Could not load type

'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.SyncDesigner.SyncFacade.SyncManager' from assembly

'Microsoft.VisualStudio.DataDesign.SyncDesigner.DslPackage, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I tired uninstall and reinstall the program. Do anybody know the answer

Comment: Hi you should tell us more, which program did you uninstall and reinstall? which version of ms Access do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem .You have to upgrade with install VS 2008 SP1(It must match windows SP).
i got the solution from microsoft connect bug traker [here's the link](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/356453/there-is-a-disconnect-between-vs-2008-and-sql-server-2008-rc0)

Comment: Many Thanks it I installed VS 2008 SP1 and connecting to database worked.

Comment: Hi all,Many Thanks. I installed VS 2008 SP1 and connecting to database worked.